# Countifs in DAX power bi

Tags: dax, powerbi

New to DAX. 
In one table I have a list of survey responders and each column is the response item to the survey:  column 1- Name, column 2- Role, column 3- Response 1.1 (char), column 4- Reponse 1.2 (char), column 5- Reponse 1.3 (char), column 6- Response 2.1 (char), column 7-Reponse 2.2 (char).

In the second table, I've calculated the total number of Respondees for each Role. The table: column 1- Role Type, column 2- total.

For the second table I am trying to create a column with the number of responses for each response. For example Role 1,  Responses 1.1 Total = 33, Response 1.2 Total= 40 ...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be a relationship between the 2 tables on Role = Role Type.  As your column names appear inconsistent, Power BI's automatic relationship generation wouldn't have worked - but you can add relationships manually.

With that relationship in place, you just need to add the Role and Response columns from the first table to any visualisation - they will count by default.  They can be shown alongside the "total" column from the second table, using the relationship.